# Clear cookies in Android

Tags: android

How can I clear all cookies in android ?

Any sample code provided will be really helpful.

Comment: In order to get a decent answer you have to get your question right. Do you want to delete the cookie data in your own application implementing the WebKit browser or do you want to clear all cookies of the default browser?

Comment: Also, you said sample code would be really helpful, which made most of us assume you want to clear cookies in Android coding, yet you accept the answer without code.. :S

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Go to browser, click a Menu button, More, Preferences, Clear cookies

Comment: Sample code was asked therefore this person was looking for how to do it programatically. @Solo_Danya's answer is the correct way

Answer (score 34):

```
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this); 
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.removeAllCookies(callback);
```

Comment: removeAllCookie is deprecated, use removeAllCookies (ValueCallback<Boolean> callback) instead

Comment: CookieSyncManager  is deprecated on API 23. The WebView now automatically syncs cookies as necessary. "You no longer need to create or use the CookieSyncManager. To manually force a sync you can use the CookieManager"

Answer (score 7):

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void clearCookies(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) { 
        CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
        CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
    } else {
        CookieSyncManager cookieSyncMngr= CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
        cookieSyncMngr.startSync();
        CookieManager cookieManager= CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
        cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
        cookieSyncMngr.stopSync();
        cookieSyncMngr.sync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! What's the purpose of calling
CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
? according to documentation 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#flush()
it's not related to clearing cookies...

Answer (score 1):

Use a CookieManager instance to manage cookies in your app. Probably in a custom `Application` class.

```
mCookieManager = new CookieManager();
mCookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
CookieHandler.setDefault(mCookieManager);
```

And whenever you want to clear, call a method like the one below:

```
public static void clearCookies() {
mCookieManager.getCookieStore().removeAll();
}
```

Comment: By adding some explanation the answer would look better.

Comment: @Onik Added some context.